# Changing CurrentPositionView in Skobbler/skmaps not working

Tags: ios, markers, skmaps

I wanted to change to default current position marker of skmaps.

I have tried this:

`self.mapView.currentPositionView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nui-img-car"]];`

But this is not working. It is still showing default position marker.

And advice please.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following in the demo project and it worked flawlessly:

```
self.mapView.currentPositionView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture"]];
```

picture.png is in the /Resources folder

[image]

Comment: I have done exactly same thing as you mentioned and png file is also proper.. even i were using that image before with google maps.. dont know what other problem is existing